# 2003 Honda Accord not responding to accelerator

Tags: honda, accord, electronic-control-module

2003 Honda Accord, a few months ago we started having problems with it. All of a sudden the CEL and traction control light came on with the d4 light blinking. Also it would idle low, shift hard, and not go into overdrive.

We had a computer check on it and it suggested the speed sensor. We got that changed and nothing was fixed, so we took it to a mechanic and he said it was the computer, and that it just needed to be programmed, and we would have to take it the Honda dealer. The next day the mechanic said that it is now no longer driveable. Now it will start but not respond to the accelerator pedal. You can push the pedal all the way to the floor and the rpms won't even move.

Also when you turn the car on it goes straight to hot. Anybody have any advice on what could be going on or how we could fix this?

**EDIT:**

The one day we called him he said he had run a bunch of test and was sure that it was the computer, that it just needed too be reprogrammed but he did not have the tool to do it so he said we would have too take it too either a Honda specialist or Honda dealer and since there are no Honda specialist around that left us with only the dealer. So I said okay that's fine when can I come pick it up too take it to the Honda place, he said well I gotta put everything back together I should have ready tomorrow I'll give you a call. Well he never called so the day after that I called back and he told me that now it was no longer running that it won't take gas, he said that it seems like the computer has completely lost the program.

Comment: What codes did the computer throw when the CEL came on?

Comment: And this went through a severe edit -- I think it has merit now that it is properly phrased.

Comment: Have you checked the throttle position sensor (TPS)? Also,for what it's worth, the mechanic saying the computer needs to be reprogrammed by the dealer sounds bogus, but I can't figure out why a mechanic would try to send you away for work he could bill you for (i.e. swapping out the ECU) unless he screwed something up. Does that seem fishy to anyone else?

Comment: Can you clarify with your mechanic what he meant when he said the computer "needed to be programmed"? There typically isn't any active "programming" that can be done on an ECU with the exception of little things like resetting the fuel trims or learning new key codes, neither of which really sounds like your problem (or really count as "programming"). You could try swapping the ECU with another one known to work (perhaps from a salvage yard) if the running theory is a failed ECU.

Comment: @MooseLucifer Yes that sounds fishy to me too.